# How do I assign functions in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with a simple program I wrote, I want to perform a certain function according to the users input. I've already used a dictionary as a replacement for a switch to do assignment but when I try to assign functions to the dictionary it doesn't execute them...
The code:

```
def PrintValuesArea():
    ## do this
def PrintValuesLength():
    ## do that
def PrintValuesTime():
    ## do third

PrintTables={"a":PrintValuesArea,"l":PrintValuesLength,"t":PrintValuesTime}
PrintTables.get(ans.lower()) ## ans is the user input
```

what did I do wrong? It looks the same as all the examples I've seen....

Answer (score 9):

You forgot to call it.

```
PrintTables.get(ans.lower())()
```

or

```
PrintTables[ans.lower()]()
```